# Docker and Windows Service in a container - permissions

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

I am moving my asp.net 4.8 app and a .net 4.8 windows service to a docker container and am having a few issues with folder permissions for the window service.

when run locally on my pc, the web app and windows service both run as 'network service'. both applications can read and write to a log folder and to a web\reports folder

i have tried to setup the folder permissions by running a powershell script as part of the dockerfile i use to create the container to replicate these permissions

but the issue i am having is that the windows service does not seem to be able to write to the log or reports folder, where as the web application can write files with no issue

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8  

# install c++ dependency
RUN mkdir c:install
ADD VC_redist_x86.exe /install/VC_redist_x86.exe
WORKDIR /install
RUN c:/install/vc_redist_x86.exe /install /quiet /norestart

# copy files
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir c:XYZ
ADD /Files/XYZ /XYZ

# setup APP POOL
RUN New-WebAppPool -Name "XYZAppPool"
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\XYZAppPool' -Name 'managedRuntimeVersion'  -Value 'v4.0'
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\XYZAppPool' -Name 'processModel' -Value @{identitytype=2}
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\XYZAppPool' -Name 'enable32BitAppOnWin64' -Value 'True' 
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\XYZAppPool' -Name 'recycling.periodicRestart.time' -Value 04:00:00

# setup web site 
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'XYZ' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\XYZ\web' -ApplicationPool 'XYZAppPool'

#setup service
WORKDIR /XYZ/service/
RUN New-Service -Name 'XYZAgent' -StartupType 'Automatic'  -BinaryPathName 'C:\XYZ\Service\XYZService.exe';
RUN New-Service -Name 'XYZReporting' -StartupType 'Automatic'  -BinaryPathName 'C:\XYZ\Service\XYZService.exe';

WORKDIR /
ADD install_services.ps1 /install/install_services.ps1
RUN powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\install\install_services.ps1
```

and ps script

```
sc.exe config "XYZAgent" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
sc.exe config "XYZReporting" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

$mypath = "c:\XYZ\logs"
$acl = Get-ACL $mypath
$accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NetworkService","FullControl","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit", "none", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $mypath $acl

$mypath2 = "c:\XYZ\web\reports\output"
$acl2 = Get-ACL $mypath
$accessrule2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NetworkService","FullControl","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit", "none", "Allow")
$acl2.AddAccessRule($AccessRule2)
Set-Acl $mypath2 $acl2
```

if any one can point me in the right direction it would be a big help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. the service exe I have creates two services. and I think the way I was installing the service was not working correctly.

i have replaced

```
#setup service
WORKDIR /XYZ/service/
RUN New-Service -Name 'XYZAgent' -StartupType 'Automatic'  -BinaryPathName 'C:\XYZ\Service\XYZService.exe';
RUN New-Service -Name 'XYZReporting' -StartupType 'Automatic'  -BinaryPathName 'C:\XYZ\Service\XYZService.exe';
```

with

```
WORKDIR /install
ADD InstallUtil.exe /install/InstallUtil.exe
ADD InstallUtil.exe.config /install/InstallUtil.exe.config
RUN c:/install/InstallUtil.exe /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack c:/xyz/service/XYZService.exe;
```

this installs it correctly and has no folder permission issues